# C++ Beginner. Adding a function and calling it fails

Tags: c++

Can you help me and let me know why this is failing?  I am getting an error as shown below:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    int a;
    string abc = "";
    cout << "Enter your Name\n";
    cin >> abc;
    cout << "Enter Your Age\n";
    cin >> a;
    cout << "Hello " << abc << ", it is nice to meet you.\n";

    StartPause();

    return 0;
}

void StartPause()
{
    cout << "\nPress any key to continue..." << endl;
    _getch();
}
```

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C3861   'StartPause': identifier not found  GreetingsConsoleApp \bpm-fs103\users...\greetingsconsoleapp.cpp   20

Comment: I recommend not using *precompiled headers* until you get more familiar with the language *and have a need for the compilers to be precompiled.*

Comment: move the function definition to before `main()`. C/C++ compilers don't time travel and won't see that you have a definition later on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler processes the compilation unit, your `.cpp` file in this case, sequentially from top to bottom.

Your `StartPause` function has been neither declared nor defined by the time the compiler finds a call to it, so it complains. It's analogous to having an undeclared variable.

To solve it, either:

1. Add a forward function declaration *before* the definition of `main`, or
2. Move the definition of `main` so that it's at the bottom of the compilation unit

In other words, either this:

```
// includes and stuff...

void StartPause();  // <-- forward declaration

int main() {
    // body definition
}

void StartPause() {
    // body definition
}
```

Or this:

```
// includes and stuff...

void StartPause() {
    // body definition
}

int main() {
    // body definition
}
```

Any of these two will solve the problem because now the compiler will know what `StartPause` is before an invocation attempt is made and will know what to do.

Answer (score 4):

Add a declaration of the function `StartPause()` before `main` like this:

```
 // Declares StartPause
 void StartPause();
 int main()
 {
    ...
 }
```

Or move the entire `StartPause` function above `main`. Compilers compile .cpp files top to bottom, so here the compiler has seen the use of `StartPause` without actually seeing a declaration for it.

Answer (score 0):

the compiler never looks down but always up so anything invoked from down will cause an error.

```
#include <iostream>                  // 1

void Foo():                          // 2

int main()                           // 3
{                                    // 4
    Foo();                           // 5

    return 0;                        // 6
}                                    // 7

void Foo()                           // 8
{                                    // 9
    std::cout << "Foo" << endl;      // 10
}                                    // 11
```

as you can see here the compiler begin from line 1 and finishes on line 11 not contrary.

when it reaches line 5 where Foo is invoked it looks behind (upwards) searching for a definition and in fact it finds a an incomplete definition (function prototype) telling it that the body of this function is coming later either in this file or in other.

now the compiler doesn't complain about the body of function so if you compile your program EVEN IF remove lines 8 through 11 (definition of Foo())!!

*** if you try to run your program without the definition of Foo you'll get
a RUNTIME-ERROR complaining about: calling a function whose definition is missing.